# Running total based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns, Year, Week, Market, Product Sale. My running total should be

I have tried the SQL script `over(order by year, Week, Market, Product ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. This works fine only for the first record set of Market & product combination. Soon as the market and/or Product change the output still computes considering the last updated data.

```
Year    Week    Market  Product  Sale   RunningTotal
2017    1       USA     Shampoo  100    100
2017    2       USA     Shampoo  100    200
2017    3       USA     Shampoo  100    300
2017    1       USA     Soap     100    400
2017    2       USA     Soap     100    500
2017    3       USA     Soap     100    600
2017    1       India   Soap     200    800
2017    2       India   Soap     200    1000
2017    3       India   Soap     200    1200
```

The result I am looking for is this

```
Year    Week    Market  Product  Sale   RunningTotal
2017    1       USA     Shampoo  100    100
2017    2       USA     Shampoo  100    200
2017    3       USA     Shampoo  100    300
2017    1       USA     Soap     100    100
2017    2       USA     Soap     100    200
2017    3       USA     Soap     100    300
2017    1       India   Soap     200    200
2017    2       India   Soap     200    400
2017    3       India   Soap     200    600
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to partition by the market and product:

```
OVER (
    PARTITION BY Market, Product 
    ORDER BY year, Week 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would suffice :-)

Comment: @zarruq In fact, the whole `ROWS ...` part is unnecessary for unbounded preceding until current row. But I like clarity of intent, and I always put the whole `ROWS` specification.

Answer (score 0):

i tried using sum()Over() Function

```
;With cte([Year],[Week], Market,Product,Sale)
AS
(
SELECT 2017,1,'USA'  ,  'Shampoo',100 Union all
SELECT 2017,2,'USA'  ,  'Shampoo',100 Union all
SELECT 2017,3,'USA'  ,  'Shampoo',100 Union all
SELECT 2017,1,'USA'  ,  'Soap'   ,100 Union all
SELECT 2017,2,'USA'  ,  'Soap'   ,100 Union all
SELECT 2017,3,'USA'  ,  'Soap'   ,100 Union all
SELECT 2017,1,'India',  'Soap'   ,200 Union all
SELECT 2017,2,'India',  'Soap'   ,200 Union all
SELECT 2017,3,'India',  'Soap'   ,200 
)
SELECT [Year],
        [Week],
        Market,
        Product,
        Sale,
        SUM(Sale)OVER(PARTITION BY Sale,Product ORDER BY RNo ) AS RunningTotal
FROm
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNo from cte
)dt
```

Expected Result

```
Year    Week    Market  Product  Sale   RunningTotal
2017    1       USA     Shampoo  100    100
2017    2       USA     Shampoo  100    200
2017    3       USA     Shampoo  100    300
2017    1       USA     Soap     100    100
2017    2       USA     Soap     100    200
2017    3       USA     Soap     100    300
2017    1       India   Soap     200    200
2017    2       India   Soap     200    400
2017    3       India   Soap     200    600
```